# Is it haram to give grandfather's first name to a child as her surname?

Tags: halal-haram, naming

I want to ask that I was recently blessed with a daughter and my husband gave her his father's name as her surname (my daughter's grandfather) instead of giving his own name to her. Like her name is "fatima mansoor" instead of "fatimah usman".

So is it permissible to do this in islam?

Comment: What does a surname indicate in your society? If it strictly indicates the name of the father and it may cause confusion regarding the parentage of the child, then it may be cautious to avoid it. Otherwise note that a grandfather is a father and is equal to the direct father in most matters of Islamic law and surnames are not always used to indicate the direct parent, indeed many people give their children a unique surname alongwith a firstname . My suggestion would be to ask a Mufti who is familiar with your local customs.

Comment: I don't beleive in society.I always prefer what our religion says about everything topic ..so their is no sir name in my in laws that is being used from the start  but my husband gave his last name to our daughter so i was confused about it ...cuz its hadith that (call them by the names of their father) so isn't that same case to change the last name of children

Comment: I am not asking you to follow your society instead of religion. however it is needed to understand what you intentions are and how your action is interpreted and this is important for the ruling. It is not just a hadith but a Quranic verse [33:5](https://quran.com/33/5?) and also a [hadith](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1802).

Comment: However it applies to lying about one's lineage or about Arabic names of the form Fatima bint Mansoor. Knowledge of your customs is needed to figure out whether this is intended in your usage of the surname. AFAIK a surname is not the same thing, a woman can be named Fatima Mansoor without implying that Mansoor is her father. Also a grandfather definitely has a lineage to his grandchildren, it is known that the Prophet called himself the [son of Abdul Mutallib](https://tinyurl.com/fd6yaatf) and called Hassan as [his son](https://tinyurl.com/27fuyc49).

Comment: https://www.islamweb.org/en/fatwa/309088/a-child-may-carry-his-grandfathers-name-as-his-surname

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed regulation on surnames in Islam; people may follow their traditions.

The classical Arabic naming used male ascendence for men, and the name of the husband for the wife. But this is not a rule in Islam.

So the rules of your country will apply.